# PyQt/PySide qfiledialog icon size

Tags: pyqt, pyside

Is there a way to have **larger icons** in the `qFileDialog`? This is for use in an image filedialog.

Anything more simple than writing my own using `qlistwidget`?

Comment: As far as I know, no.
I'd suggest you make your own class for a QFileDialog like popup. That shouldn't be too difficult to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can [set an icon provider](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html#setIconProvider) on the `QFileDialog`.

The icon provider must be a subclass of [QFileIconProvider](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfileiconprovider.html), which reimplements the `icon()` method in order to return custom icons for the requested file-types.